# facebook FQL get photo full size src

Tags: facebook, get, facebook-fql, photo, src

```
SELECT pid,link,src,src_big FROM photo WHERE aid = '143587452330654_112887'
```

I'm using this code to retrieve image src. But I want to get big image src (which one you can see under the photo - Download)

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f3xxe4f3

Comment: I think src_big will always give you the biggest image size.

Comment: That image can have a maximum width or height of 720px. But When we Download from manually It's has bigger one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method

here is my query

```
SELECT pid,src,images FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM photo WHERE album_object_id=$object_id

foreach( $tagged_graph as $key => $value )
{
    $highres = array_shift($value['images']);
    echo 'src : ', $value['src'] , ';
    echo 'hq : ' ,  $highres['source'] , ';
}
```